# Unable to download certificates and configure provisioning profile correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to set certificates for iOS project that I am working on. My teammate has sent me two files .p12 and .mobileprovision. I have added certificates in keychain successfully also provision profile is added in Xcode. But I am getting error i.e.
[image]

When I click on provisioning profile drop down and select download profile this is what I am getting.
[image]
I tried different profiles in build settings but nothing seems to work. So, did I missed a step or what's the issues?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes but I have to revoke the certificates, couldn't use existing team certificates.

Comment: Good news then. What about choosing my answer as correct?

Comment: I would have definitely done that already, but that was not the solution (as I didn't got the solution yet). So sorry cannot do that as it will distract people facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using the same bundle id, delete derived data and run it again.

Comment: Yes bundle id is same confirmed multiple times. Now deleted derived data but still same issue. Problem is that I cannot sign code otherwise it is running fine on simulator

Comment: Add UDID of current device on apple developer account.

Comment: That's not the issue. Also when you are running directly on device there is no need to add UDID manually.

Comment: You device UDID must be added to your profile (Adhoc) to make it run on device.

Answer (score 0):

On simulator u don't need to sign it, so it will run.

Seems that your team id is not the correct one for that PP or your developer id is not added to that PP.

PP = Provisional Profile

Ur bundle id is correct. Go to ur apple account and check team and developer id of that PP.